# pgfplotstabletypeset to html with pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a latex table made with pgfplotstable typeset to html with pandoc, for example:

```
  \begin{table} 
    \centering
  \pgfplotstableset{
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
      fixed zerofill,
      precision=2,
      display columns/0/.style={string type},
      col sep=comma]{images/prvsflow.txt}
  \caption{Variation of pressure drop with flow rate (m/s)}
  \label{tab:pvv}
\end{table}
```

. If I just use it straight with

```
pandoc -s example.tex -o example.html
```

then it gives

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>[tab:pvv]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [htlatex](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html), which seems to do a much better job with tables than pandoc, and also works quite nicely with tables made with pgfplotstabletypeset